# Keras in Python: LSTM Dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am building an LSTM network.
My data looks as following:

```
X_train.shape = (134, 300000, 4)
```

X_train contains 134 sequences, with 300000 timesteps and 4 features.

```
Y_train.shape = (134, 2)
```

Y_train contains 134 labels, [1, 0] for True and [0, 1] for False.

Below is my model in Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(300000, 4), return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

Whenever I run the model, I get the following error:

```
Error when checking target: expected lstm_52 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (113, 2)
```

It seems to be related to my Y_train data -- as its shape is (113, 2).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output shape of your LSTM layer is `(batch_size, 300000, 4)` (because of `return_sequences=True`). Therefore your model expects the target `y_train` to have 3 dimensions but you are passing an array with only 2 dimensions `(batch_size, 2)`.

You probably want to use `return_sequences=False` instead. In this case the output shape of the LSTM layer will be `(batch_size, 4)`. Moreover, you should add a final softmax layer to your model in order to have the desired output shape of `(batch_size, 2)`:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(300000, 4), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) # 2 neurons because you have 2 classes
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```